# qt qstring toStdString loss of minus sign

Tags: qt, qstring

I am using a qstring and using the function toStdString(). When I do this I lose a minus sign:

```
'332-_09I_W'
```

this text becomes:

```
'332_09I_W'
```

What can I do to prevent this?

EDIT: Actually, the problem is not when i use toStdString(), it is when I set the text in my qTextEdit. The change occurs here:

```
myTextEdit->setHtml(myString);
```

Comment: I write:  `QString qs("332-_09I_W");
    std::string ss = qs.toStdString();
    cout << ss << endl;` and the output is OK.

Comment: yes, sorry I found out that wasn't the problem I was having. Thanks for investigating this to double check me.

Comment: That's not really a HTML string, is it?

Comment: The problem doesn't just occur with the text edit. When i try and set the text of a line edit the soft hyphen disappears. I'm even having troubles pasting the soft hyphen into this edit box.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried:

```
QString qs("332-_091_W");
std::string st = qs.toStdString();
ui->textEdit->setHtml(st.c_str());
```

It gives no problem to me. Which version of Qt are you using?

However, from the documentation:

> setHtml() changes the text of the text edit. Any previous text is removed 
>   and the  undo/redo history is cleared. The input text is
>   interpreted as rich text in html format.
>       Note: It is the responsibility of the caller to make sure that the text is correctly  decoded when a QString containing HTML is created
>   and passed to setHtml().

The minus/hyphen symbol is ambiguous in HTML, try to change it in the QString (before passing it to `setHtml()`) with `&minus;`

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback! it's not a regular hyphen/minus that I'm having problems with. It's the soft hyphen (unicode U+00AD). If you type in the unicode into microsoft word, highlight it and press Alt+x you will see the character I am trying to display in any line edit in Qt 4.7.4.

Comment: this is the case for when I use setText and setHtml

Comment: '&shy;' it seems a weird character... I can't see it in many apps. Change the symbol, if you can.